# Bit-vector sign extension in simulink

Tags: matlab, concatenation, verilog, simulink

I am currently trying to translate the following Verilog command into Simulink:

```
assign A = {{14{B[15]}},B[15:0],2'b00};
```

This line sign-extends the 16-bit vector and multiplies it by 4. For example, given the 16-bit input `B = 0100110110101101` the output would be 32-bit `A = 00000000000000010011011010110100`:

The Simulink this operation can be performed by the following blocks:

[image]

But I thought, there might be an easier way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> If the RHS side of the assignment is signed datatype, then it would be
>   having signed extension (MSB will be extended) and if unsigned
>   datatype then unsigned extension (0 will be extended).

So here, if your B is of type `reg signed` or any other signed datatype, then it will be having signed extension, otherwise not.